# copy contents of a remote location to a local file in ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to copy the contents of a remote location file to some local file after an ssh connection has been made.

```
 begin
    ssh = Net::SSH.start("localhost", "user")
    logger.info "conn successful!"
    results = conn.exec!('ruby somefile "#{arguments}"')
    #code to copy the contents of a.txt in remote location to local file
    #IO.copy_stream (localfile, remotefile)
 rescue
    logger.info "error - cannot connect to host"
 end
```

I tried using IO.copy_stream but that doesn't work. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Net::SCP` (which requires Net::SSH) to transfer files:

```
Net::SCP.download!("remote.host.com", "username",
  "/remote/path", "/local/path",
  :password => password)
```

More info here: https://rubygems.org/gems/net-scp